# How do I change the URL configuration of my existing Django web app on Pythonanywhere?

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

Is there a straightforward way for me to change the current URL of my Django web app (www.example.com) to another one (www.example2.com)? I've configured example2.com's CNAME record already to point at username.pythonanywhere.com, and have included '.example2.com' in Django settings of the existing Django project. www.example.com is now live and running well.

Question also asked on [PA Forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1181/#id_post_8245).

Comment: Alright I fixed this by dumbing down and manually starting a new django project and copying the files over, since it wasn't that large of a project. Still, would appreciate a better way to fix this the next time it happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [PythonAnywhere docs on pointing a new domain at an existing web app](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/UsingANewDomainForExistingWebApp).